# Look for repeated characters in a string

Tags: java, string, character

I know this question was asked many times, but I didn't find any of the answers helpful in my case. I have a method that receives a String. I want to check if any of the characters in the string are repeated. If so the method will return an empty String. If not it will return the String back.
The method is looking for any repeated character in the String.

```
private String visit(String word) {
    int count = 0;
    if(word == ""){
        return "<empty>";
    }
    //alphabet is an array that holds all characters that could be used in the String
    for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){  
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){

            if(alphabet[i] == word.charAt(j)){
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 2){                 
                return "";                                              
            }
        }
        count = 0;
    }           
    return word;        
}
```

Comment: `I already made a method but its not working correctly, so I won't waste your time and post it here.` Except that that's half of the question. We need to see it.

Comment: Please provide a code sample. Also you can modify all other useful ways to check if character is repeated in String to use a character of the String and just to loop over all characters of the String

Comment: Ok. Have you created any program or method to achieve this? Please share.

Comment: are you sure alphabet contains all possible characters?

Comment: Check my answer out, the regex can be adjusted to your need easily

Comment: check my example here https://ideone.com/X5o3Ps

Comment: @Antonio yes  it contains all possible characters

Comment: @BhavO I was actually looking to check for duplicates using loops, if that is possible?

Comment: Yes, its possible but then there are many different ways todo it, you need to be clear about what your criteria is

Comment: can you show where you initialize alphabet so we could re-run your code?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I publish my solution to this:

```
package main;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasDups("abc"));
        System.out.println(hasDups("abcb"));
    }

    public static String hasDups(String arg) {
        String[] ar = arg.split("");
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        boolean noDups = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < ar.length && noDups; i++) {
            if (ar[i].equals(ar[i-1])) noDups = false;
        }

        if (noDups) return arg; else return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` have method `toCharArray()` you can use it instead `split`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way of doing what you want, but you can use two `for` loops to check each character against all the other characters to see if it is repeated.

```
public static String hasRepeated(String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) return "<empty>";
    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
            } else if (Character.toString(charArray[i]).
                    equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(charArray[j]))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Note: This code assumes that the case of the character doesn't matter, it just checks if it is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /**
    * Returns the index of the first character repeated, or -1 if no repeats
    */
   public static int firstRepeated( String s ) {
      if ( s != null ) {
         int n = s.length();
         for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
            int indx = s.indexOf( s.charAt( i ), i + 1 );
            if ( indx > 0 ) {
               return i;
            }
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

This works!!

```
public static String checkDuplicate(String str)
{
    int count = 0;

    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<charArray.length;j++)
        {
            if(charArray[i]==charArray[j])
            {

                count++;
                if(count==2) break;
            }
        }
        if(count==2) break;
    }
    if(count==2)
        return "";
    else
        return str;
}
}
```

Comment: why -1 ?? did you even run this code?! It works perfectly fine.